# Ruby: How do I assign values in the controller when using nested forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have 3 models: Employers, Partners and Collaborations.

As an Employer, I want to add a record to my Partner model and to my Collaboration model to be able to indicate a collaboration between a Partner and a Employer. I therefore have the following columns in my database/tabels.

**Models**

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :partners, :through => :collaborations
end

class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :employers, :through => :collaborations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collaborations
end

class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employer
  belongs_to :partner
end
```

**Tables**

```
Collaborations
  employer_id:integer
  partner_id:integer
  tarive:string

Partners
  added_by:integer
  name:string
```

Because I want to be able to add a Partner/Collaboration within 1 form, I use nested forms. So I can add a partner (name, etc) and a collaboration (tarive, etc) in one go.

My (simple_form) form looks like this (I have named_space resource).
Te reduce clutter, I removed as much HTML mark_up as I could, this is not the issue.

**Form**

/views/employer/partners/_form

```
= simple_form_for [:employer, @partner], html: { multipart: true } do |f| 
  Partner
  = f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

  = f.simple_fields_for :collaborations do |ff|
    Tarive
    = ff.input :tarive, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }

= f.button :submit, "Save"
```

My controller looks like

```
class Employer::PartnersController < ActionController::Base
  def new
    @partner = Partner.new
    @partner.collaborations.build
  end

  def create
    @partner = Partner.new(partner_params)
    @partner.collaborations.build
    @partner.added_by = current_employer.id
    @partner.collaborations.employer_id = current_employer.employer_id
    @partner.collaborations.partner_id = @partner.id
    @partner.collaborations.added_by = current_employer.id

    if @partner.save
      redirect_to employer_partner_path(@partner), notice: "Succes!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def partner_params
    params.require(:partner).permit(:id, :name, collaborations_attributes: [:id, :employer_id, :partner_id, :tarive])
  end
end
```

**Problem**

The problem/question I have is this. The attributes are assigned nicely and added in the model. But I want to add a `employer_id` as well, which I have in `current_employer.employer.id` (Devise). I do not want to work with hidden forms, just to avoid this issue.

I assigned 'parent' models always like `@partner.added_by = current_employer.id` and that works beautifully.

When I use:

```
@partner.collaborations.employer_id = current_employer.employer_id
```

I get an error, saying `@partner.collaborations.employer_id` is empty.

**Question**

How can I assign a variable to the nested_form (Collaboration) in my controller#create?
Or more specifically: how can I assign `current_employer.employer_id` to `@partner.collaborations.employer_id`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@partner.collaborations.employer_id`?

Comment: Sorry, typo - should be (collaborations) plural. I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing three things `current_user`, `current_recruiter` and `current_employer` which one you are using?

Comment: to simplify the question: current_employer - I uniformed the question

Comment: What is the value of `current_employer.employer_id`?

Comment: As you are using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` you don't need to assign employer_id explicitly.Rails will automatically handle it for you.Just call @partner.save and the related record will be created automatically.
You can have some idea from [this] (http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) link.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways:

> 1. Merge the params
> 2. Deal with *objects*, not foreign keys

Personally, I feel your `create` method looks really inefficient. Indeed, you should know about `fat model skinny controller` - *most* of your associative logic should be kept in the model.

It could be improved using the following:

```
#app/controllers/employers/partners_controller.rb
class Employers::PartnersController < ApplicationController

   def new
      @partner = current_employer.partners.new #-> this *should* build the associated collaborations object 
   end

   def create
      @partner = current_employer.partners.new partner_params       
      @partner.save ? redirect_to(employer_partner_path(@partner), notice: "Succes!") : render('new')
   end

   private

   def partner_params
       params.require(:partner).permit(:id, :name, collaborations_attributes: [:tarive]) #when dealing with objects, foreign keys are set automatically
   end
end
```

This would allow you to use:

```
#app/views/employers/partners/new.html.erb
= simple_form_for @partner do |f| #-> @partner is built off the current_employer object
  = f.input :name
  = f.simple_fields_for :collaborations do |ff|
    = ff.input :tarive
= f.submit
```

... and the models:

```
#app/models/partner.rb
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employer, foreign_key: :added_by

    has_many :collaborations
    has_many :employers, through: :collaborations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :collaborations
end

#app/models/collaboration.rb
class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employer
    belongs_to :partner

    belongs_to :creator, foreign_key: :added_by

    before_create :set_creator

    private

    def set_creator
         self.creator = self.employer_id #-> will probably need to change
    end
end

#app/models/employer.rb
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :collaborations
    has_many :employers, through: :collaborations
end
```

This may *not* give you the ability to set `tarive`, however if you cut down the manual declarations in your model, we should be able to look at getting that sorted.

The main thing you need to do is slim down your code in the controller. You're being very specific, and as a consequence, you're encountering problems like that which you mentioned.

Comment: Not sure why the `creator` field is needed since a Collaboration record will be added for every Employer-Partner relationship, so the creator field will always be the same as the employer_id field. Other than that, totally agree with your answer, upvoted.

Comment: Thanks - it was tough to think through it, I doubt it will work out the box but hopefully it will point in a better direction

Comment: Will let you know when I have a chance to try it out (tonight)

Comment: Thanks bud - don't hold your breath if it doesn't work right away; we can work to fix it